# How to monitor Grafana

Tags: grafana, prometheus-alertmanager

I have set up Grafana in my kubernetes cluster for monitoring. But I am really curious about **How to monitor the monitoring system(Grafana)??**

One solution I can think of is to set up an alert in prometheus-alertmanager so that whenever Grafana pod goes into error/CarshLoopBackOff state I get an alert.

Answer (score 0):

Grafana is able expose own metrics in Prometheus format (https://grafana.com/docs/administration/metrics/). So it is not a big deal configure scraping and send alert in case job down

```
- alert: GrafanaDown
expr: up{job="GrafanaDown"} == 0
for: 1m
labels:
  severity: critical 
annotations:
  summary: "Instance {{ $labels.instance }} is down"
  description: "{{ $labels.instance }} of job {{ $labels.job }} is down."
```